# Odoo Add link into exception popup

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

Is it a right way to add a link into `UserError` message? Something like this:

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/'
raise UserError("Some text: " + '<a href="' + url + '">'))
```

I've got button which switches state to 'done', but before it there is test.

```py
@api.multi
def set_state_inwork(self):
    self.check_condition_for_set_state_inwork()
    for r in self:
        r.state = "inwork"`

    def check_condition_for_set_state_inwork(self):
        if self.request_id.lab_id.is_check_condition_for_workbook:
            import datetime
        wb_collection = []
        for r in self:
            data = self.env['labs.request'].search(['|', '&',
                                                    ('protocol_desired_date', '<', r.request_id.protocol_desired_date),
                                                    ('protocol_desired_date', '>=', fields.Date.from_string(r.request_id.protocol_desired_date) if r.request_id.protocol_desired_date else fields.Date.from_string(fields.Datetime.now()) + datetime.timedelta(days=7)),
                                                    ('protocol_desired_date', '!=', False)])
            if data:
                for d in data:
                    wb_list = d.workbook_ids.filtered(lambda x: x.state == 'awaitstart' and x.is_estimated_research_date is False and x.lab_employee_id == r.lab_employee_id).mapped("name")
                    if wb_list:
                        wb_collection.append(wb_list)
        if wb_collection:
            raise UserError("You must add data at this documents: " + ", ".join(x[0] for x in wb_collection))
```

Now it is just numbers of documents, I want to add links to this documents.

Comment: I think you can't do that, they are not rendered to HTML they will be just texts.

Comment: @ElegantOdoo Is there another implementation of this case?

Comment: why do you want this behavior ? what you want to do exactly edit your question may be we could help with another idea

Comment: @ElegantOdoo update question

Comment: You can achieve this by creating your own wizard, then catch the error in your code and return the wizard action showing the link using url widget